# Kendo-ui app drawer css config

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I'm kind new at mobile programming and I found some issues with css in kendo-ui.

[image: App drawer menu]

1- How can I eliminate this gray border around collapsible menu 1?
2- I'm not being able to ser border to 0 on each section...
3- below the section 9, is a wide gray area... couldn't set it to the same dark gray color of the entire menu.

code below:

```html
<div data-role="drawer" id="app-drawer" class="drawer-menu">
    <div data-role=header>
        <div data-role="content" class="drawer-profile">

            <a href="views/profile.html" data-role="button" style="color: yellow; horizontal-align: middle">edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <ul data-role="listview" class="drawer-menu">
            
            <li class="drawer-li drawer-menu">
                <div data-role="collapsible" class="drawer-collapsible drawer-menu km-icon-right">
                    <h3 style="font-weight: normal" class="drawer-menu">1...</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                        <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="views/nearme.html?##Search=nearme">11</a></li>
                        <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="views/nearme.html?##Search=address">12</a></li>
                        <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="views/categorylist.html">13</a></li>
                        <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">Serviços on-line</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="views/promolist.html">2</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">6</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">7</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">8</a></li>
            <li class="drawer-menu"><a href="#">9</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.drawer-li {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    
}
.drawer-collapsible {
    margin: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width: 0 !important;
}
.drawer-collapsible h3 a {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
}
.drawer-profile {
    background: #34393D;
    height: 90px;
    /* opacity: 0.5; */
    font: Segoe !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
}
.drawer-menu {
    background: #34393D !important;
    color: white;
    font: Segoe !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody did respond to this question, but I could figure out how to solve by myself. I'll post the solution just to help anybody coming with the same doubt.

```css
.drawer-menu li {
    background: #34393D !important;
    color: white;
    font: Segoe !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-width: 0px !important;
}

.drawer-menu div {
    background: #34393D !important;
    color: white;
    font: Segoe !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-width: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Configuring classes for the  was not working, nor for the . So I set the css for the childs  and  inside the class ".drawer-menu" that was attributed for the app-drawer. the result in the image attached:
[drawer menu solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtFqK.png)